# Xperia handset - cannot send files using bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer, sony-ericsson-xperia-x8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xperia handset - cannot send files using bluetooth](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4826/xperia-handset-cannot-send-files-using-bluetooth)

My friend has a Sony Ericsson Xperia (most probably X8) handset which is an Android based smartphone. He is not able to send files through bluetooth but able to receive. I don't exactly remember the version of Android which he is currently having. He has tried to download and install the required update using the same phone (he has internet connected) from http://www.sonyericsson.com but not able to install it. So, he asked me to help him. Which version of Android do you think he has? Does it seem like he does not have Android 2.1 installed. It is written [here](http://www.sonyericsson.com/update/?cc=in&lc=en&pid=xperiax8) (click on Xperia X8) that

> If your phone already has Android 2.1,
>   you can use your mobile network* or a
>   WiFi connection to download the
>   software.

Is it possible that he does not have updated Android and so not able to download? If so, does he need to upgrade to Android 2.1 first? Should it be done by connecting it to a PC?

Comment: Off topic for Super User but do try on the [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Voted to close this migrated version.